# What does 已出口直封 mean?

Tags: translation

*My first question here, sorry if it's not a good fit.*

I am tracking a parcel in Chinese, but I do not know what 已出口直封 means.

I know that 广州互换局 means Guangzhou exchange bureau/office, and 已出口开拆 means that the parcel has been opened by customs, but I don't know the other part.

For context:

> 2016-04-10 13:03 广州互换局, **已出口直封**
>
> 2016-04-10 09:13 广州互换局, 已出口开拆

I have checked Google Translate, but it just says `straight seal`, which is meaningless to me.

Translated.net also says `We have been exported straight seal`. I have no idea what this means though.

Comment: try jukuu:市邮电局与大约70个国家和地区的邮局建立了邮件直封关系。direct route mail relations, therefore possibly "exported by direct route"

Comment: This is a good question. The jargon makes native speakers confused too, so I think it's even helpful to native speakers. I would like to see a professional answer (like with some authoritative references?) to explain "what's going on with the package" other than its literal meaning.

Comment: Your question is fine. Thanks for showing some effort to translate the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some research on this topic. It seems that China post system uses a series of terminology for international logistics shipment tracking, but the terms are not well explained by official, so even native speakers are confused about what they are saying.

Examples of those terms:

出口直封：Packages receive by local post office, then merge into bigger packages by destination country.

进口开拆：Packages arrive at destination country, then open and divide into small packages.

进口互封：Merge small packages from last step into bigger packages by destination Province/City.

互封封发：Transfer packages from last step to destination Province/City.

互封开拆：Packages arrived at destination City/Province, then divide into small packages.

You can refer to the following Zhihu post for more details (In Chinese):
[跨国邮件的状态问题](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/36854553)

Answer (score 4):

I guess this should mean the inspection was successful and your package is directly(直)  (re)packaged(封)

According to http://community.ebay.cn/thread-1200132963-1-1.html (this is the most helpful page I have found)
A translation is "departure from outward office of exchange". A Chinese explanation is "这表示包裹己经顺利的通过海关检查,重新打包好,交给航空公司,等待航班飞走", it means "this indicates the package passed the inspection by custom and had been repackaged, sent to airline and waiting the plane to fly"

Answer (score 1):

According to [Baidu Zhidao](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/328602946847012725.html), I think the most important point is that the package had not ever been **unwrapped** and sent out to your destination.

A Chinese explanation: "总包在国内已经出口国外之前已经封好，直接邮寄到当地国家，称为直封。也就是说从中国至目地国家的包裹，**没有拆开过邮袋**，到了目地国家才拆开，再由目地国家按地区分开，在按地区装袋封发，进行邮寄配送。"