# What does this mean in English, please?

Tags: translation, meaning

[广州市]【广州国际中心】已出口直封 What does this mean in English? I am expecting a parcel to be delivered.

Comment: You'll find most of the answer here: [What does 已出口直封 mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/what-does-%E5%B7%B2%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%A3%E7%9B%B4%E5%B0%81-mean).  Other than that: 广州市 = Guangzhou (city) and 广州国际中心 = Guangzhou International Center.

Answer (score 0):

Guangzhou city, Guangzhou International Center, Already exported for direct delivery while sealed (meaning they won't open it again for inspections)